# What would cause CSS to become disabled when performing a database schema update?

Tags: database, theming, updating

I am running Drupal 7.26 on a GreenGeeks using their EcoSite service.

In addition to Drupal core files I'm using the following modules:

1. Context
2. Delta
3. Webform
4. ctools
5. imce
6. imce_wysiwyg
7. omega_tools

There are more modules but are very standard like token, views, libraries, pathauto, etc...

I am also using Omega 3 as my base theme. I've created a child theme from it and customized it. Then using Delta + Context created a specifically configured theme for this particular landing page. Also, I am using Drupal's blocks to place content within the Omega themes' regions.

Looking at the Status Report I need to perform Database updates to update certain module database schemas because they are out of date. Those modules are:

**system module**
7079 - Convert the 'filesize' column in {file_managed} to a bigint.

**image module**
7005 - Add a column to the 'image_style' table to store administrative labels.

**node module**
7014 - Add an index on {node}.language.

**taxonomy module**
7011 - Drop unpublished nodes from the index.

I place my site into maintenance mode and perform the script update. I get no errors. I disable maintenance mode and view my site. Upon viewing my site, all the styling is gone. The page displays the embedded images but no CSS images or any CSS styling.

I reverted my database back to its original configuration. Then I asked for GreenGeeks support for help and they disabled "ModSecurity". I attempted to update my database schema with the same result, my page displays without any styling. They said they couldn't help any further.

To expand on my original question, is there a way to manually update each modules schema one by one to see which is causing this error?

Below is what the site looks like BEFORE making the update
[image]

Below is what the site looks like after making the update
[image]

Let me know if more information is required.

Thank you for any help, it's appreciated,
Michael.

Comment: I forgot to mention, on the status report I do see a notice, it reads:

Notice: Undefined index: value in theme_status_report() (line 2584 of /home/fhtransp/public_html/modules/system/system.admin.inc).

I am not a programmer and do not understand to relevance of this message.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a cache problem? Perhaps the aggregated CSS file you are trying to call has been deleted. Try disabling CSS aggregation on the performance page before running the database updates and see if that fixes the problem. (of course, this assumed that you have CSS aggregation turned on - just an idea.)

Comment: @AdamBalsam - Thank you for the idea. I didn't think of it. Before making the update I simply disabled aggregate CSS and JavaScript and upon saving it and viewing the webpage, it looks all messed up. I cleared caches, viewed it on another browser it still looks all messed up. I even updated the database schema and then tried enabling/disabling CSS and JS aggregate but the same result, the site looks messed up. From your experience, where else could I do to look up or try to observe/monitor an issue like this?

Comment: Well, to answer your second question, yes - there is a way to manually update each module's schema one by one. On the update page, expand the list of available updates. Each module has a select list next to it and the ones that need to be updated will have something other than "no updates available selected". Change all of those to "no updates available" except for the one you want to test. Repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still having trouble. I did do something slightly different. I reset the database and only updated an error pertaining to the "Public files directory". I used an .htaccess file from another site with a stable version of Drupal and overwrote the one on this trouble site. The result without performing any updates was the same, the site became completely messed up. What could this tell you about what I should do to fix this issue? On a scale of Drupal knowledge, I am maybe a 3 out of 10. Thank you, Adam for your continued help and guidance. I am learning.

Comment: I think your next step would be to figure out exactly what CSS files are missing and whether they are missing (as min 404s) or if the tag that references them is missing from the output. That should give you a clue as to where the problem is coming from. Leave CSS aggregation off while you troubleshoot.

Comment: SUCCESS!! Thanks for that last bit of advise. I disabled aggregation before but never bothered to inspect the page. I noticed global.css was the only stylesheet being called despite the view port in desktop dimensions. This gave me the idea of making an insignificant minor change to my global, narrow, and normal stylesheets, recompile them and then over-writing the CSS on live. Clearing caches and refreshing my browser caused the site to maintain its styling in all views. I performed the database schema update and the site maintained its styles. THANK YOU for your great help!